# I want to make a multisite CMS in laravel 4. How Can I Implement template system in laravel 4 for a multisite CMS

Tags: content-management-system, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel ie L4. I want to build a multisite CMS in L4. I want to implement a template system so each subdomain of site may have a different template and different components in template .

How I can do it in L4.

Please guide me.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of template you are referring to. Are you trying to use different output templating system like Blade for one site and let's say Smarty for another?

Comment: Hi,Thanks. My main objective is to create a CMS in laravel so that I can make different sites using subdomain( like multisite in wordpress). And I want to use default template engine of laravel(Blade) so each site can be loaded on different template using different components/modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you are asking the procedure for making and implementing theme. Anyway try this Laravel 4 package.

https://github.com/teepluss/laravel4-theme